# Performance Mongodb java driver

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm using mongodb java driver in my project for execute queries (finds, aggregate, mapreduce,...) over a big collection (5 millions of documents)

The driver version is:

```
<!-- MongoDB driver-->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
  <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

My problem is when I use the api find with some filters from java, the operation takes 15 sec.

```
....
Iterable<Document> messageList = collection.find().filter(... some filters).sort(... fields);

// Find documents
for (Document message : messageList) {
....
// some code
....
}
```

I check the mongo server log file and see the trace is a *COMMAND* instead of a *QUERY*:

> 2015-09-01T12:11:47.496+0200 I COMMAND  [conn503] command b.$cmd command: count { count: "logs", query: { timestamp: { $gte: new Date(1433109600000) }, aplicacion: "APP1", event: "Event1" } } planSummary: IXSCAN { timestamp: 1, aplicacion: 1 } keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:19089 reslen:44 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 19090 } }, MMAPV1Journal: { acquireCount: { r: 19090 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 19090 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { R: 19090 } } } 14297ms

If I run the same query from mongodb client (Robomongo), it takes 0.05 ms.

```
db.getCollection('logs').find({ timestamp: { $gte: new Date(1427839200000) }, aplicacion: "APP1", event: "Event1" })
```

and in the server log is as *QUERY*

**All queries that are made (find, aggregate, ...) with the driver java commands are transformed?** The performance is much worse than mongo shell.

Comment: Did you try `collection.find(... some filters...).sort(... fields);` instead? This does not use the `.filter` method of `MongoCursor` but instead provides the filter criteria when opening the cursor. That would be closer to your shell query.

Comment: Yes, I try but same result.

Comment: I just noticed that your shell query does not have a `sort`. Maybe that's the culprit?

Comment: No. it has sort clause. I don`t set it in comment for clearer

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is when you ran the query in mongo shell it will return only top 20 result at a time, here you are trying to read all the document and put it into array

try this query and see

List messageList  = collection.find(filter).sort(...field).limit(20).into(new ArrayList());

It's highly recommended to create a index on query field.

Comment: I don´t think so. i've queries with limit clause for pagination with same result. I know that it's recommended to create index.

Comment: are you facing same issue after limiting the result ?

Comment: I just saw, the issue performance wasn't the find query. It takes the same time as robomongo client. (15 ms.) In addiction to this find, I do a count() query to get total number of documents (for do pagination). This query takes more than one minute, there are 2.5 million of documents.